# Работа с клавиатурой без терминала

Tags: c, windows, клавиатура

Можно ли на c работать с клавиатурой напрямую, минуя терминал? Т.е. получать состояние клавиатуры без getch().

Comment: Средствами только языка и стандартной библиотеки - нет. Вы спрашиваете о какой-то конкретной ОС?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, Windows10, если не в стандартной, я бы хотел узнать библиотеку для такой работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется, в Windows можно работать с клавиатурой напрямую, минуя прокладки. Для этого в WinAPI есть большой набор функций и сообщений, см. раздел документации [Keyboard Input](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/keyboard-input). Особое внимание обратите на функцию [GetKeyState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) и сообщения [WM_CHAR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-char), [WM_KEYDOWN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-keydown), и [WM_KEYUP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-keyup).

Насчет библиотек - сомневаюсь, что есть какие-то, стоящие упоминания. Работа с клавиатурой достаточно проста, и полностью покрывается стандартной библиотекой C/C++ для консольного ввода, и WinAPI для чего-то посерьезнее.